# Use eval to set unknown property

Tags: python, eval

I have an User class, that has multiple properties inside it, and I also have addPoint method for User class, which allows user to input points into any of it's properties. However, there can be up to like 500 properties, everyone can have different ones, etc. So it would be a pain in the ass to code every property with "if: - elif:". Now this is what I tried to do, to make it much easier and cleaner:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 0
        self.speed = 0

    def addPoint(self, property, amount):
        eval("self."+property) = eval("self."+property) + amount
```

And now when I'd do fe.

```
u = User()
u.addPoint("health", 5)
```

I would like it to do this: `self.health = self.health + 5`, and that's what I used the `eval()`s for. However, Python's just giving me error: `can't assign to function call`. I'm not trying to assign the `eval()` function call itself, I'm trying to assign the returned value from `eval()`, so how could I do this the easiest way?

Comment: As to the error: if you think about it, your example would evaluate to `0 = 0 + 5`, since `eval` in line 7 returns a value, not a pointer or quote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `eval()`, use [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) and [`getattr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) instead:

```
setattr(self, property, getattr(self, property) + amount)
```

Comment: Thank you sir, works and looks even better, will accept asap :)

Answer (score 2):

use a `dictionary` instead of `eval()`:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 0
        self.speed = 0
        self.properties={}

    def addPoint(self, property, amount):
        self.properties[property] =self.properties.get(property,0)+amount 

        #self.properties.get(property,0) returns 0 if the property was not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's best solution, but you can use **dict** attribute of object like this:

```
def addPoint(self, property, amount):
    self.__dict__[property] = amount
```

`__dict__` attribute stores all attributes of object, and you can access them in very clean and simple way.

Comment: Note that by going to the instance `__dict__` you may be bypassing `@property` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use function settattr, provided by Python standard library - quick example:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         setattr(self, "a", "b")
... 
>>> A().a
'b'
```

Comment: Martijn Pieters already mentioned that in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12234807/846892).